# Wordpress site Images not displaying in Safari IPhone

Tags: css, iphone, wordpress, image, woocommerce

In the eCommerce site built with woocommerce in wordpress images are not rendering in Iphone safari browser.

Checked in Iphone 7 and 8. Images get rendered when phone screen is switched to landscape orientation. 
[image: When screen changed to landscape displays images]
[image: Initial screen - portrait display does not render]

But Chrome has no issue. Also Ipad no issue. Any other device or browser so far checked has no issue.

Only issue with Iphone Safari browser - portrait screen.

Website: http://www.212motoring.com/shop/

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is probably a theme or plugin issue, i would try deactivating plugins and see if finally it is caused by the theme, then i will dig further on the theme ui.

Comment: Works fine in Safari iOS 11.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be problem with one of the libraries. As a work around, if the device was IOS, an auto click on the menu bar is made to display the inventory.